# Updating task fields while generating task from catalog request item

Tags: servicenow

[image]

[image]

I want to use this os version and vcenter variables and append it to the task's short description field while task is generated.
I need to know where to code, while catalog task generation for this requirement.
Any help is appreciated........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you guys should hire a ServiceNow developer. :-P

I assume your catalog task is generated via a workflow? If so, you'll have to go into the workflow using the workflow editor, check it out using the hamburger menu at the top-left, double-click the activity (box) that generates the task, and there will be a script field.

In the script field, enter the following at the bottom of the script:

```
task.short_description = task.short_description + ' - VAR1: ' + current.variables.FIRST_VARIABLE_NAME + ' - VAR2: ' + current.variables.SECOND_VARIABLE_NAME;
```

Replace "VAR1" and "VAR2" with whatever you want them to say (like if the variable is "printer", enter "printer:" instead of "VAR1:").

Also, replace "FIRST_VARIABLE_NAME" and "SECOND_VARIABLE_NAME" with the two variable names you wanted to use.

This will result in the following format for the short description:

ORIGINAL SHORT DESCRIPTION - VAR1: VAR1_VALUE - VAR2: VAR2_VALUE